# Justify if a subset form a topology on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

Justify the subset $T$ of $P(\mathbb{N})$ consisting of $\emptyset$, $\mathbb{N}$ and the subsets $O_l=\{nK+l:n\in \mathbb{N}, 0 \leq l<K\}$ forms a topology on $\mathbb{N}$.

I believe this statement is false, as I think the sets $O_l$ are all singletons, and so the subset T is not closed under union, because $T$ does not consists any two-elements set.

Am I right? please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Is $K$ a fixed quantity?

Comment: I am not sure, that's the question I have been given. I guess it is a fixed quantity. otherwise, maybe a compact set I guess.

Comment: Okay; I’ve answered on that assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $K>0$, the sets $O_\ell$ are infinite. For example,

$$O_0=\{nK:n\in\Bbb N\}\;;$$

this is $\{0,K,2K,3K,\ldots\}$ if your $\Bbb N$ includes $0$, and $\{K,2K,3K,\ldots\}$ if it does not. Similarly, if $K>1$,

$$O_1=\{nK+1:n\in\Bbb N\}\;,$$

which is either $\{1,K+1,2K+1,3K+1,\ldots\}$ or $\{K+1,2K+2,3K+1,\ldots\}$, again depending on whether your $\Bbb N$ includes $0$ or not.

You’re right that this family of sets is not closed under unions, but not for the reason that you gave.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I guess you mean the union of $O_0$  and $O_1$ is not in the subset $T$?

Comment: @user138017: Or indeed any union $O_i\cup O_j$ with $i\ne j$. If you’re familiar with modular arithmetic (congruences) at all, notice that $O_\ell$ is just the non-negative part of the congruence class of $\ell\bmod K$.

Comment: Yeah, I have learnt a bit about the congruences. Thanks a lot, that helps a lot.

Comment: @user138017: You’re welcome.